# Issues with rewriting all http and https domain traffic to https based url

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get all variation

```
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
https://www.example.com
https://example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

to all redirect to

```
https://www.example.com
```

I have the following mod_rewrite block:

```
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

which seems to do all but one:

`https://example.com` does not get redirected to

`https://www.example.com` as expected

If I removed the condition:

```
ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
```

so that it affects both http and https, it still does not behave as expected.

Where am I going wrong with this please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make an SSL-to-SSL redirection using `.httaccess`

You'd have to use separate VirtualHost entry for every domain (provided your web-server supports [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for chipping in there. Quick question for you please: Are you saying that this solution is not possible outside of an SNI capable Apache version - 2.2.15, for example? Also, what if the redirection is not within the .htaccess file but instead in the vhost conf file? Thanks

Comment: Apache 2.4 is also SNI compatible, the problem is that SNI happens before `.htaccess`, so to decide that https://example.com should be redirected the directive must be in `httpd.conf`